# Equivalent of Alt in Microsoft Office

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I usually press `Alt` in Microsoft Word or Excel so I get a label with the next key to all the menu functions (see picture with keyboard labels when pressing `Alt` in Word).

Is there any equivalent for LibreOffice? It would really help me to learn&use the keyboard shortcuts.

[image: Office Word when Alt is pressed]

Comment: LibreOffice does not have ribbon, but its menubar mnemonics are highlighted when you press `Alt`. For other keyboard navigation read [official documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Shortcuts_Accessibility).

Comment: @N0rbert: Not entirely correct; see my answer.

Comment: @JimK But mnemonics are highlighted by `Alt` anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In LibreOffice if you press alt button for 1 sec you can see highlighted keys for the shortcut. same as word you can type alt+f to open file menu.

you can refer this for more details.
https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Shortcut_Keys_in

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> has the same function in LibreOffice as it does in any other application.  The underlined letters show what happens when you press that key.

LO 5.3 and newer has an experimental feature called [MUFFIN](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/132681/will-ribbon-come-to-libreoffice-ever/?answer=132686#post-id-132686) that looks like the MS Ribbon interface.

[image: menu with ribbon]

However, currently <kbd>Alt</kbd> is tricky to use with MUFFIN.  For example, click on *Find & Replace* and then close it.  Now the MUFFIN bar has the focus, so you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to open Nav̲igator.